# document.evalute function giving exception

Tags: xml, android, dom, xpath

I have a code like

```
res = doc.evalute(xpathExpr,doc,
                  function(prefix) {return namespaces[prefix] || null;},
                  XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null );
```

Here doc is DOM document node

When i run for loop like this

```
for(i in doc) alert(i);
```

it gives evaluate method

but when i tried to use this method on dom node it giving me error like

xpathResult not defined...

i'm working in android browser

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

```
XPathResult.ANY_TYPE
```

It's not guaranteed that the DOM Level 3 XPath `XPathResult` interface will actually be represented as a `window` member called `XPathResult`. In fact none of the DOM interfaces are specified to be reflected as constructor-functions in `window`. In most non-IE browsers, many of them are. But Android's browser doesn't seem to support `evaluate` on an `HTMLDocument`; I guess that's why it doesn't also provide `XPathResult`.

So if you want to get a static member like `ANY_TYPE` the only reliable way to do it is to have an instance of that class already, and access `.ANY_TYPE` from that. Since you don't have an XPathResult at this point, you're probably best off just saying `0`.

Comment: thanks man for your reply.....

But what's the point of giving evalute method support when it's return type object is not there....

it's something like 

one function returning int and int is not defined ....

secondly

if xpathResult is not defined and selectnode is also not there....

how come i use xpath query in the android browser...

Comment: Again, you should not be using `XPathResult` directly in *any* web browser. It is only a side-effect that it is present as a global variable in some browsers. Like trying to fetch `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` (which won't work in IE); there is no standard that says `window.XPathResult` should exist at all.

Comment: got your point now...

one last help...

can you tell me how to use xpath query in android browser.

i have a Document dom node xpath expression,

i have to return the list of node satisfying the xpth in xml doc.

Comment: OK, I've just loaded the emulator to check, and it seems that unlike full-blown Chrome, the Android Browser does not support DOM Level 3 XPath on either XML or HTML documents. I don't get `evaluate` listed in `for(i in doc) alert(i);` at all.

Comment: oh sorry i checked myself....   there is no evaluate method 
i must have seen in chrome or firefox....

thanks very much for your help....

is there any way to handle these thing bcz i have to use xpath ....

at any cost...  means...  my app needs that...

is there any other way...  like i can call java from javascript  and do the stuff releted to xpath as backgroud process using java...

if you know let me know....   thanks...

Comment: Possibilities: http://coderepos.org/share/wiki/JavaScript-XPath http://llamalab.com/js/xpath/ http://goog-ajaxslt.sourceforge.net/ http://mcc.id.au/xpathjs

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Components.interfaces.nsIDOMXPathResult` instead of `XPathResult`.